# R: is it possible to abstract a list of arguments out of piped functions like select() and summarize()?

Tags: r, dplyr

For example:

```
dataset1 <- masterData %>%
  select(
    variable1,
    variable2,
    variable3,
    ...,
    variablen
  ) %>%
  group_by(groupingVariable1) %>%
  summarize(
    metric1 = ...,
    metric2 = ...,
    metric3 = ...,
    ...,
    metricn = ...
  )
```

Let's say I also want to create a `dataset2` and a `dataset3` (etc...) where the *only* difference between their construction is the variable passed to `group_by()` (for example for `dataset2` using `group_by(groupingVariable2)` and for `dataset3` using `group_by(groupingVariable3)`.  Other than that, the arguments passed into `select()` and `summarize()` will be identical from one dataset to another.

Is there a way to create a `selectArguments` object and a `summarizeArguments` object so that I do not have to duplicate argument edits across all the dataset constructions should anything change?

What would be the best way to achieve something like this:

```
dataset1 <- masterData %>%
  select(
    selectArguments
  ) %>%
  group_by(groupingVariable1) %>%
  summarize(
    summarizeArguments
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `select` explicitly when you are summarising. As you have difference only in grouping variable for different dataset why not create a function.

```
library(dplyr)

summarising_fun <- function(df, groupingVariable) {
   df %>%
     group_by_at(groupingVariable) %>%
     summarize(
     metric1 = ...,
     metric2 = ...,
     metric3 = ...,
     ...,
     metricn = ...
  )
}
```

Then you can call the function for various dataset using

```
summarising_fun(dataset1, "groupingVariable1")
summarising_fun(dataset2, "groupingVariable2")
summarising_fun(dataset3, "groupingVariable3")
```

---

If you want to pass the grouping variable as unquoted variable try using curly-curly operator which will change the code to

```
summarising_fun <- function(df, groupingVariable1) {
  df %>%
   group_by({{groupingVariable1}}) %>%
   summarize(
      metric1 = ...,
      metric2 = ...,
      metricn = ...
  )
}
```

and can be called as

```
summarising_fun(dataset1, groupingVariable1)
summarising_fun(dataset2, groupingVariable2)
summarising_fun(dataset3, groupingVariable3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .dots = grouping_variables_as_a_list to specify variable grouping variables.

for example this could be your code:

```
grouping_vars_1 <- c('column_1','column_2')
grouping_vars_2 <- c('column_3','column_4')

process_data <- function(df, grouping_vars){
      dataset1 <- df %>%
                  select(
                    selectArguments
                  ) %>%
                  group_by(.dots = grouping_vars) %>%
                   summarize(
                    summarizeArguments
                   )

      return(dataset1)
}

output_1 <- process_data(your_data_frame,grouping_vars_1)
output_1 <- process_data(your_data_frame,grouping_vars_2)
```

Comment: The `.dots=` is being phased out. The recommendation for the latest version of dplyr would be to use the `rlang`  triple-bang operator (`!!!`) to inject multiple parameters into a function call.